# How can I tell when my weapons will lose sharpness?

Tags: monster-hunter-3-ultimate

My weapons have a tendency to lose sharpness at the *worst* times. How can I predict when the sharpness will go down so that I can use a whetstone before my next battle, rather than just being stuck in horrible circumstances constantly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to tell exactly how much durability your current sharpness level has, unfortunately.

Generally, most attacks will "consume" the same amount of durability, so you can generally get an idea of how much swinging is needed to use up the current level.  You do need to connect with monsters in order for the durability to be consumed; attacking the air won't do anything at all.

There are couple factors to watch out for, though.  As you get further on, you will run into monsters that have hardened areas.  If your weapon is not sharp enough, it will bounce off, interrupting your combo.  Not only do bounced attacks do less damage, but they also consume more durability in the process.  Note that only cutting weapons can bounce, though; blunt weapons, like the hunting horn and hammer, won't bounce.  Neither will ranged weapons.

Some weapons also have special attacks that will consume more than the regular amount of durability, when those attacks connect.  The Gunlance's Wyvern Fire, especially, eats durability like candy.

Comment: Alternately, if you have problems with sharpening in battle, grab the Sharpener armor skill. It greatly reduces the amount of time it takes to sharpen your weapon, making it roughly the same amount of time it takes to consume a Potion or Ration.